# Segue called twice using Text View Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I'm trying to make my first iOS app - board games tracker. I am using `textView` delegate to choose and then display players - `textViewShouldBeginEditing`. When I click it, it sometimes performes the segue twice and I don't know why.

In the second controller, when I come back, I use navigation controller delegate method.

Important parts of my viewController with textView:

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    if textView == playersNameView {
        segueKey = "all"
    } else if textView == winnersNameView {
        segueKey = "winners"
    } else if textView == loosersNameView {
        segueKey = "loosers"
    }

    if textView == pointsView {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addPoints", sender: self)
    } else if textView == playersNameView || textView == loosersNameView || textView == winnersNameView {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "choosePlayers", sender: self)
    }
    return false

}


//MARK: - Managing segue
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "chooseGame"?:
        let controller = segue.destination as! ChooseGameViewController
        controller.gameStore = gameStore
        controller.selectedGame = selectedGame
    case "choosePlayers"?:
        let controller = segue.destination as! ChoosePlayersViewController
        controller.key = segueKey
        setAvailablePlayers()
        switch segueKey {
        case "all"?:
            controller.availablePlayers = availablePlayers
            controller.selectedPlayers = selectedPlayers
            if let game = selectedGame {
                controller.maxPlayers = game.maxNoOfPlayers
            }
        case "winners"?:
            controller.availablePlayers = availablePlayers
            controller.selectedPlayers = winners
            if let game = selectedGame {
                controller.maxPlayers = game.maxNoOfPlayers - loosers.count
            }
        case "loosers"?:
            controller.availablePlayers = availablePlayers
            controller.selectedPlayers = loosers
            if let game = selectedGame {
                controller.maxPlayers = game.maxNoOfPlayers - winners.count
            }
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Wrong segue key")
        }
    default:
        preconditionFailure("Wrong segue identifier")
    }
}
```

and my second view controller - ChoosePlayersViewController

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if let controller = viewController as? AddMatchViewController {
        switch key {
        case "all"?:
            controller.selectedPlayers = selectedPlayers
            controller.deselectedPlayers = deselectedPlayers
            controller.setPlayersPoints()
        case "winners"?:
            controller.winners = selectedPlayers
        case "loosers"?:
            controller.loosers = selectedPlayers
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Wrong key!")
        }
        controller.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
}
```

EDIT

I have a workaround for now - using `Date` i check if the time between segues is greater than 1 second. If it is greater, then it performs segue, if not - it doesn't. Works for now, but I hope for more elegant answer.